# Problema na Submissão do App no Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Estou submetendo uma versão atualizada do meu app(sdk 23) no Play Store e está dando este erro quando tendo publicar na seção no Beta Tester:

> Não é possível publicar a configuração pelos seguintes motivos: Não é
>   possível fazer o downgrade de dispositivos que usavam anteriormente as
>   permissões M (SDK 23 e superiores) para APKs que usam as permissões de
>   estilo antigo (SDK 22 e inferiores). Isso ocorre na mudança da versão
>   32 (SDK 23) para a versão 29 (SDK 19).

Já fiz as mudanças de requestPermission para o sdk 23. Mas para contemplar os aparelhos com android <23 meu manifest está assim:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Meu build.gradle está assim:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.app.vertz"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 36
    versionName "2.8"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Mesmo assim recebo a mensagem de erro:

> Não é possível fazer o downgrade de dispositivos que usavam
>   anteriormente as permissões M (SDK 23 e superiores) para APKs que usam
>   as permissões de estilo antigo (SDK 22 e inferiores). Isso ocorre na
>   mudança da versão 32 (SDK 23) para a versão 29 (SDK 19).

Comment: Se não estou enganado essa mensagem é de que você está tentando enviar um apk que tem o targetSdkVersion menor que 23 quando já enviou algum outro apk com o targetSdkVersion >= 23, independente de ser enviada para produção ou para testes, uma vez que você publicou um apk com sdk 23 você nunca mais pode voltar atrás

Comment: Olá Leandro, o targetSdkVersion desta minha atualização é 23. Coloquei o build.gradle para ficar mais claro. Estou esquecendo de alguma coisa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que você tentou carregar um APK para produção que usa o modelo de permissões M (nível 23). Isso significa que você não pode fazer o *downgrade* para versões anteriores. Isso é devido ao modelo de permissões alterado entre essas diferentes versões.

Veja aqui no [Console do desenvolvedor do Google](http://www.androiddocs.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html):

> Observe que os *rollbacks* não são suportados devido aos requisitos de
>   versão de aplicativos da plataforma Android. Se você precisar
>   reverter, verifique antes lançar um APK anterior com um novo número de
>   versão. No entanto, esta prática só deve ser utilizada como último
>   recurso, uma vez que os utilizadores perderão o acesso a novas
>   funcionalidades e a aplicação antiga poderá não ser compatível com as
>   alterações ou formatos de dados do servidor, por isso certifique-se de
>   executar testes alfa e beta antes da atualização.

Para corrigir é necessário:

1. Reconstruir o projeto em seu estado anterior com o número de versão
   mais alta (deve ser maior do que todas as versões enviadas
   anteriormente)
2. Reenviar